# Antimalware Scan Interface (AMSI) equivalent for Linux App Services

Tags: linux, azure-web-app-service, antimalware

We have used Antimalware Scan Interface (AMSI) successfully on Windows hosted IIS. The application is now moving to Linux based Azure App Services.

Is there an equivalent for Linux App Services to scan malware?

Constraints - I am in need of a OS based API (such as AMSI) and unable to install an AV such as ClamAV.

Comment: Did you manage to get anywhere with this?

Comment: No progress unfortunately.

Comment: Thanks for responding. I've gone with a ClamAV in docker approach (and the web app calling in to that as necessary)